# Как в HTML расположить блоки горизонтально?

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="header">

    <p class="header-text1">About</p>
    <p class="header-text2">Project</p>
    <h1 class="header-text3">Homeland</h1>
    <p class="header-text4">Resources</p>
    <p class="header-text5">Features</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Имею ввиду элементы внутри `header`.

Comment: Потому что это блочные элементы.

Comment: ответили вам верно. Рекомендую эту стаью(https://tproger.ru/articles/how-css-flexbox-works/) для прочтения. Флексы вам очень пригодятся в будущем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header {
  background-color: green;
  /* Рсположить элементы по горизонтали */
  display: flex;
  /* Выровнять элементы по оси Y */
  align-items: center;
  /* Выровнять элементы по оси X */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="header">

    <p class="header-text1">About</p>
    <p class="header-text2">Project</p>
    <h1 class="header-text3">Homeland</h1>
    <p class="header-text4">Resources</p>
    <p class="header-text5">Features</p>

  </div>
</div>
```